# How to fix Chrome's Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"

Tags: google-chrome, rest, http, browser

I'm using Advanced REST Client to test external API which requires me to specify
`Connection: Keep-Alive`. The connection fails (NO RESPONSE) and inspecting Chrome console I noticed `Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"` followed by `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`

Is there any Chrome settings that allow me to override this? BTW, the API works when I use external tools like APIGee. I've tried Chrome CORS extension (Allow Control Allow Origin) but still unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that chrome is refusing to load a resource that has an invalid or expired SSL certificate.  Even if you could get it to bypass that it would be a bad idea as it would make man in the middle attacks easier in your application.

My suggestion would be (if you trust the server or if it's running locally) to import that certificate to your store so it's trusted in your development environment. If the cert is expired and it's hosted locally look at the documentation on how to change the certificate or to add a self signed one (which you then also would add to your trusted sites)

How to add a self signed very to your store

[For Mac](http://www.robpeck.com/2010/10/google-chrome-mac-os-x-and-self-signed-ssl-certificates/%23.VCh0T6Y8KJI)

[For windows](http://www.poweradmin.com/help/sslhints/ie.aspx)

You'll have to restart chrome for it to see the certs in the store after doing this

Again, be sure you trust these certs origin as they'll be considered trusted as if a legit CA HAD issued them

Comment: im having the same issue, but i just created my certs??? `WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header is missing`